# How to clip a circular path inside a rectangle in Android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ondraw, clipping, custom-draw

I've read over 20 questions/answers but I still can't get what I want. I want to cut a circle inside a rectangle as seen below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setARGB(180, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
    Path circularPath = new Path();
    circularPath.addCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(circularPath, Region.Op.REPLACE);
    canvas.drawColor(0x00000000);


}
```

My background (`setARGB`) displays correctly, however nothing is clipped. I've also tried different `Op` values other than `REPLACE`, forced software rasterization (as I've read on some Android versions `clipPath` doesn't support some of the `Op`s) by calling `setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` on constructor, but no avail. How do I achieve the desired effect?

**Note:** My minimum SDK version is 15, so I don't need to support anything lower than 4.0.

Comment: did you try Region.Op.DIFFERENCE ?

Comment: @pskink yes, just tried now again to make sure. Unfortunatelly, nothing happens.

Comment: DIFFERENCE just works fine to me,  try to canvas.drawColor with Color.RED, then clipPath and then drawColor 0x88000000

Comment: @pskink could you post a sscce as an answer?

Comment: just use like this: canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
            Path circularPath = new Path();
            circularPath.addCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 300, Path.Direction.CCW);
            canvas.clipPath(circularPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
            canvas.drawColor(0x66000000);

Comment: @pskink it works. please post this comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `clipPath` before `drawRect`.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int width = this.getWidth();
    int height = this.getHeight();

    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);

    float rectWidth = Utils.dpToPx(100.0f);

    Path circularPath = new Path();
    circularPath.addCircle(width / 2.0f, rectWidth / 2.0f, rectWidth / 3.0f, Path.Direction.CCW);
    canvas.clipPath(circularPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect((width - rectWidth) / 2.0f, 0.0f, ((width - rectWidth) / 2.0f) + rectWidth, rectWidth, mPaint);
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

Try clipping your path in `dispatchDraw()`:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.clipPath(mClipPath, mRegion); // previously created path & region

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

Remove the path clipping code from your `onDraw` method, and that should do it.

**Edit:**

When creating your path, make sure you do so only after a measure occurred, for example:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    mClipPath.reset();
    float radius = Math.min((float)getMeasuredWidth() / 2f, (float)getMeasuredHeight() / 2f) + 5;
    mClipPath.addCircle((float)getMeasuredWidth() / 2f, (float)getMeasuredHeight() / 2f, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a possible cause to why it's not working for you

Comment: Copy/pasted it. Still no change. I heavily doubt there should be an overridden method other than `onDraw` though, as all the examples I've seen involve only that method.